# Azure Speech To Text: Conversation Transcribing userid always return $ref$

Tags: c#, speech-to-text, azure-cognitive-services, azure-speech

Using sample code to transcribe conversation, but on recognized event i always get `$ref$` when calling `e.Result.UserId`.

I use 16-bit samples, 16 kHz sample rate, and a single channel (Mono) format for voice signatures.
And 32-bit samples, 32 kHz sample rate, and a single channel (Mono) format for Transcribing conversations.

All code from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/how-to-use-conversation-transcription-service

Is there any ideas? or .wav sample files i can use?

**UPD**

Seems like audio is not in the right format. Should be 16bit,16kHZ, 8 channels (Stereo Left=1, Stereo Right=2, Mono=3, Mono=4, Mono=5, Mono=6 ,Mono=7, Silenced Mono=8).

Here you can find enrollment_audio_steve.wav, enrollment_audio_katie.wav and conversation katiesteve.wav. It's in a correct format. However it doesn't allow to create signature from enrollment_audio_katie.wav. So it work with Steve.

It still seems that's it's only work with SpeechSDK devices. But i was able to recrod own audio, based on that format.

Comment: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/tree/master/samples/csharp/sharedcontent/console you can find the .wav files here...